# python: indentation error : indent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, indentation

I am having trouble with indentation. can someone help me please:errors are in the first and second if statements

```
data_graph = {"a" : ["b", "d", "f"],"b" : ["c", "f"],"c" : ["d"],"d" : ["b"],"e" : ["d", "f"],"f" : ["d"]
}

def depth_first_search(data_graph):
def depth_first(nodes_visited, data_graph, nodes):

    if nodes in nodes_visited:
        pass
    else:
        nodes_visited[len(nodes_visited):] =[nodes]
        print ("Nodes visited:", nodes, len(nodes_visited)) 

    for i in data_graph[nodes]:
        if i in nodes_visited:
            pass
        else:
            depth_first( nodes_visited,data_graph, i)

nodes_visited = []
while  (len(data_graph) > len(nodes_visited)): 
     for nodes in data_graph:
        if nodes in nodes_visited:
            pass
        else:
            depth_first(nodes_visited, data_graph, nodes)

depth_first_search(data_graph)
```

Comment: What is going on with your `def depth_first_search(data_graph):`? You have another function you are trying to define directly underneath. If your intention is to have the `depth_first` function inside the `depth_first_search`, then everything underneath `depth_first_search` needs to be indented *inside* that function.

Answer (score 1):

Note the nested function was not indented.

```
data_graph = {"a" : ["b", "d", "f"],"b" : ["c", "f"],"c" : ["d"],"d" : ["b"],"e" : ["d", "f"],"f" : ["d"]
}

# you need to indent this function inside a function
def depth_first_search(data_graph):
    def depth_first(nodes_visited, data_graph, nodes):

        if nodes in nodes_visited:
            pass
        else:
            nodes_visited[len(nodes_visited):] =[nodes]
            print ("Nodes visited:", nodes, len(nodes_visited)) 

        for i in data_graph[nodes]:
            if i in nodes_visited:
                pass
            else:
                depth_first( nodes_visited,data_graph, i)

    nodes_visited = []
    while  (len(data_graph) > len(nodes_visited)): 
         for nodes in data_graph:
            if nodes in nodes_visited:
                pass
            else:
                depth_first(nodes_visited, data_graph, nodes)

    depth_first_search(data_graph)
```